# Framework not found CFNetwork for architecture x86_x64 (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, architecture, frameworks, cfnetwork

I have a code developed in Xcode where the base SDK is 10.5 and it's working well but when I try to change it to another architecture (x64) I got an error:
Linker command failed with exit code 1
Detail: framework not found CFNetwork for architecture x86_x64